# Pandas add new column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a List of list values as shown below:

```
res = [["a", "b", "b"], ["d", "e"], ["f", "g"]]
```

I have a data frame as shown below:

```
df__ = pd.DataFrame({'memberid': ['a1','a2','a3'],
                   'labels':[0,1,2]})
```

It'll look as shown below:

```
              labels memberid
        0       0       a1
        1       1       a2
        2       2       a3
```

I want to add another column called `prob` based on the `labels`column, the value constituting from `res` list. The output will look as what you get when you run the below:

```
df__ = pd.DataFrame({'memberid': ['a1','a2','a3'],
                   'labels':[0,1,2],


       labels memberid   prob
0       0       a1       a b b
1       1       a2       d e
2       2       a3       f g
```

So basically, I use the `labels` value as the index for `res` list and populate the `prob` column.

I have run the code below:

```
for i in range(len(df__["labels"])):
           k =  df__.iloc[i]["labels"]
           df__["prob"] = " ".join(res[k])
```

But I don't get the output that I want from the above code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please see my answer. The problem is, you keep reassigning `df__["prob"]` under the `for/loop` hence the last value wins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re your error, it lies on this:

```
df__["prob"] = " ".join(res[k])
```

You keep reassigning `df__["prob"] =` **1 value**, which is the latest `" ".join(res[l])`
Hence at the end the whole column is just the last value.
To correct this, you can change to this:

```
prob = []
for i in range(len(df__["labels"])):
    k =  df__.iloc[i]["labels"]
    prob.append(" ".join(res[k]))
df__['prob'] = prob
```

Also you can use `map` and `lambda`, like this to achieve the same result, this is more efficient than your attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df__ = pd.DataFrame({'memberid': ['a1','a2','a3'],
                   'labels':[0,1,2]})
res = [["a", "b", "b"], ["d", "e"], ["f", "g"]]
# you can map the values from '__labels' and feed to 'prob' with lambda
df__['prob'] = map(lambda x: ' '.join(res[x]), df__['labels'])

df__
   labels memberid   prob
0       0       a1  a b b
1       1       a2    d e
2       2       a3    f g
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!! :) It works! And thank you for showing the pandas way to do it too.

Comment: @user1452759, not a problem! glad it helps :)